# JQGrid 4.4.0: 'date' formatter srcformat/newformat now tries to format date when source date's format does not match srcformat

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter, date-formatting

I have a JQGrid that has a date column.  I use the date formatter to format the date to a `m/d/Y` format.  Previously, if the format of the source date did not match the `srcformat` I passed in the `formatoptions`, it just wouldn't format the date.  JQGrid v4.4.0 now attempts to format the date no matter the source format, and comes up with dates that are wayyy off :-).

The dates I have populating into this column could either be in the correct format already (`m/d/Y`) or be in the format I have defined in `srcformat` (`Y-m-dTH:i:s`).

Is there a way in JQGrid 4.4.0 to not try to parse dates that do not match the `srcformat`?

---

My colModel def for column:

```
{name:"date", index:"date", label:"Date", width:85, jsonmap:"date", hidden: false, formatter:'date', sorttype: 'date', formatoptions:{srcformat:'Y-m-dTH:i:s', newformat:'m/d/Y'}, searchrules: { date: true } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own issue :)

I created a custom formatter and used the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) JQuery library to help out in parsing the date.

Basically the formatter only formats the date to m/d/Y format if it is in the Y-m-dTH:i:s format; otherwise, it assumes it's already in the m/d/Y format and leaves it be.

```
/**
 * This function formats the date column for the summary grid.
 * 
 * The grid could be populated with dates that are in m/d/Y format or in Y-m-dTH:i:s format; need
 * to account for this; want the dates to end up being in m/d/Y format always.
 * 
 * @param cellvalue     is the value to be formatted
 * @param options       an object containing the following element
 *                      options : { rowId: rid, colModel: cm} where rowId - is the id of the row colModel is the object of the properties for this column getted from colModel array of jqGrid
 * @param rowObject     is a row data represented in the format determined from datatype option;
 *                      the rowObject is array, provided according to the rules from jsonReader
 * @return              the new formatted cell value html
 */
function summaryGridDateFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    // parseExact just returns 'null' if the date you are trying to 
    // format is not in the exact format specified
    var parsedDate = Date.parseExact(cellvalue, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"); 

    // if parsed date is null, just used the passed cell value; otherwise, 
    // transform the date to desired format
    var formattedDate = parsedDate ? parsedDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy") : cellvalue;

    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@icats: thanks for this! it really helped - I was starting to get pretty frustrated...

I actually had to modify your function a bit. 
I was getting a **timestamp** field from the DB, which was coming back through JSON as the value in **milliseconds** (i.e. meaning the actual value was something like: 1343314489564). Therefore I added a second check for parsedDate, as below:

```
/**
 * This function formats the date column for the  grid.
 *
 * The grid could be populated with dates that are in m/d/Y format or in Y-m-dTH:i:s format; need
 * to account for this; want the dates to end up being in m/d/Y format always.
 *
 * @param cellvalue     is the value to be formatted
 * @param options       an object containing the following element
 *                      options : { rowId: rid, colModel: cm} where rowId - is the id of the row colModel is the object of the properties for this column getted from colModel array of jqGrid
 * @param rowObject     is a row data represented in the format determined from datatype option;
 *                      the rowObject is array, provided according to the rules from jsonReader
 * @return              the new formatted cell value html
 */
function dateFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    // parseExact just returns 'null' if the date you are trying to
    // format is not in the exact format specified
    var parsedDate = Date.parseExact(cellvalue, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    if(parsedDate == null )
        parsedDate = new Date(cellvalue);

    // if parsed date is null, just used the passed cell value; otherwise,
    // transform the date to desired format
    var formattedDate = parsedDate ? parsedDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : cellvalue;

    return formattedDate;
}
```