# Error with jqgrid date formatting

Tags: date, jqgrid, formatter

Server is returning a string with the date in this format `"2/6/2013"` after we bind to the formatter, it appears like this: `"12/4/2007"`.

```
{ 
    name: 'DueDate', 
    index: 'DueDate', 
    width: 110, 
    align: 'center', 
    resizable: false, 
    formatter:'date', 
    formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' }, 
    datefmt: 'm/d/Y' 
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying source format in the `formatoptions`.

ie;

```
formatoptions: { srcformat:'d/m/Y',newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
```

Or you can use a custom formatter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401612/jqgrid-4-4-0-date-formatter-srcformat-newformat-now-tries-to-format-date-when)